# Test data set for calendar data

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, calendar, email

Is there anything comparable to the Enron Corpus, but for calendar data? I already do text categorization based on Enron Emails but I would like to combine my approach with other business data, preferably calendar data which correlate to the mails.

Comment: Did you find a good dataset with calendar entries?